# Python Regex - find all occurences of a group after a prefix

Tags: python, regex

I have a strings like that:

```
s1 = 'H: 1234.34.34'
s2 = 'H: 1234.34.34 12.12 123.5'
```

I would like to get the elements separated by space after the H inside groups, so I tried:

```
myRegex = r'\bH\s*[\s|\:]+(?:\s?(\b\d+[\.?\d+]*\b))*'
```

It's fine with string s1

```
print(re.search(myRegex , s1).groups())
```

I's giving me: ('1234.34.34',) => It's fine

But for s2, I have:

```
print(re.search(myRegex , s2).groups())
```

It's sending back only the last group ('123.5',), but I'm expecting to have ('1234.34.34', '12.12', '123.5').

Do you have an idea how to get my expected value?

In addition, I'm not limited to 2 groups, I may have much more...

Thanks a lot

Fred

Comment: can you add `s3` to your post or is it the same as `s2` as the error case suggests?

Comment: If you repeat the capturing group, you get the value of the last repetition which in this case is `123.5` One way to get the values of the numbers is to capture the data in group 1 and then split on a space afterwards. `\bH: (\d+(?:\.\d+)+(?: \d+(?:\.\d+)+)*)\b` https://regex101.com/r/2nz6B7/1 Or you could make use of the [PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library `(?:\bH:|\G(?!A)) \K\d+(?:\.\d+)+` https://regex101.com/r/SVY8Ov/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your pattern, in this part `(?:\s?(\b\d+[\.?\d+]*\b))*` you have a capturing group inside a repeating non capturing group which will give the capturing group  the value of the last iteration of the outer non capturing group.

The last iteration will match `123.5` and that will be the group 1 value.

One option is to match the whole pattern and use a capturing group for the last part.

```
\bH: (\d+(?:\.\d+)+(?: \d+(?:\.\d+)+)*)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b0AM70/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ahE2pe)

If you have the group, you could use split:

```
import re

s2 = 'H: 1234.34.34 12.12 123.5'
myRegex = r'\bH: (\d+(?:\.\d+)+(?: \d+(?:\.\d+)+)*)\b'

res = re.search(myRegex , s2)
if res:
    print(res.group(1).split())
```

Output

```
['1234.34.34', '12.12', '123.5']
```

---

Using the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), you could make use of `\G` to get iterative matches for the numbers and use `\K` to forget what was currently matched, which would be the space before the number.

```
(?:\bH:|\G(?!A)) \K\d+(?:\.\d+)+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SVY8Ov/1) | [Python demo](https://rextester.com/VLD2077)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved my issue. In fact, in my initial strings, I want to match 'H: xxx xxx' inside bigger strings. So for me, right solution is: 1st a regex, then a split

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string will always start with H:, you can do as follows :

```py
s2 = 'H: 1234.34.34 12.12 123.5'

output = s2.split("H: ")[-1].split()
```

Output will be 
`['1234.34.34', '12.12', '123.5']`

The first split will allow you to get all your character after the `"H: "`

The second split will split your sentences following your spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your examples, you don't need a regex, [split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) will suffice:

```
s1 = 'H: 1234.34.34'
s2 = 'H: 1234.34.34 12.12 123.5'

match1 = s1.split()[1:]
match2 = s2.split()[1:]

print(match1)
print(match2)
```

---

```
['1234.34.34']
['1234.34.34', '12.12', '123.5']
```